# Google Analytics code error implementing in .asp file

Tags: forms, asp-classic, google-analytics

I am implementing Google Analytics in a form page.

The problem comes after the form is sent by a user.

In the form landing page, the GA tracking code is partly duplicated in the body, creating duplicated stats for the landing page.

I've checked my asp file and have no clue on what I could be doing wrong.

I hope someone can point me on the right direction, thanks in advance.

```
<head>
  <%if Request.QueryString("enviado") = 1 then%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var google_conversion_id = 97885866;
    var google_conversion_language = "es";
    var google_conversion_format = "2";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "BNPUCI6xqQIQ-ofj0gM";
    var google_conversion_value = 0;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http:www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/978895866/?label=BNPUCI6xqQIQ-ofj0gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.ysm_customData = new Object();
    window.ysm_customData.conversion = "transId=,currency=,amount=";
    var ysm_accountid = "1FJ1MOC128JN2MQEDCC45EREVMC";
     document.write("<SCR" + "IPT language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'" + "SRC=//" + "srv3.wa.marketingsolutions.yahoo.com" + "/script/ScriptServlet" + "?aid=" + ysm_accountid + ">
     </SCR" +"IPT>");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount, 'UA-10880766-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<%end if%>
</head>
```

Comment: This code contains AdWords conversion tracking, Yahoo conversion tracking, and last Google Analytics code, all being displayed only when ?enviado=1 in the URL.
What's the question ?

Comment: Since all of the code to send data to Analytics is on the front end, take a look at the landing page source in production and see where "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);" is called twice. Also check in any .js files that might be included.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late, but maybe this helps other people as well.

When I understand this correct you are referring to the fact, that the GoogleAnalytics Tracking is fired twice. 
If yes, I also had a similar problem on my page. The problem however did only occur in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer.

This problem was in my case related to a empty `src` tag in my code. In Firefox and Chrome  "" means "this URI" and therefore my tracking was fired twice.

I could fix that by removing the yahoo pixel in my code.

You can read also: [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225554) for more info.